# woff font creating

Tags: fonts, unicode

I have a open type unicode font created for largely Devanagari codepoints. I want to use it on a website. I converted the font to woff using fontforge. using default options. But once the font is created [image: What should look like this] looks like  [image: this]
Is fontforge the right program to convert font to woff format? 
Has anyone experience and succcess with any other program and successfully converted a non-latin script font to woff format?

Comment: can someone add tags for fontforge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that combining rules of Devanagari are placed in the are places in different places for Windows7/Vista and WindowsXP/linux .
The combining rules with respect to Windows7/Vista were present and the ones related to Windows XP and linux render devanagari and the conjuncts consonants in Devanagari were not present.

I checked this excellent [font](http://svayambhava.org/index.php/en/fonts) developed by Mihail Bayaryn and how the combining rules were set. I am in the process of fixing it in this font and will upload the results soon.